# Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8084" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I'm trying to print a pdf generated by jspdf and loaded on iframe, but I'm getting that error message:

"DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8084" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

this is my code:

```
  <iframe id="pdf-prueba" name="pdf-box"></iframe>


function open(){
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [55, 5]);
    var data = pdf.output('datauristring');
    $('#pdf-box').attr("src", data).load(function(){
        document.getElementById('pdf-box').contentWindow.print();
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: @empiric it's not duplicate, i have the same Protocol, hostname and port  that my domain

Comment: Then you should include more information about your environment instead of letting us guess what's happening

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8084" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

This message is valid because when you load iframe with the pdf you set the src attribute with a datauristring, not a blob.

A simple solution is based on:

- create a blob from pdf (i.e.: pdf.output('blob')..)
- convert the blob to URL (i.e.: URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF))

The policy is violated using your approach because the protocols (http/data) are different:

- one is http://localhost:8084
- the iframe is: data:application/pdf

Another mistake is:

```
document.getElementById('pdf-box')
```

You must use the id and not the name, so change it to:

```
document.getElementById('pdf-prueba')
```

The following changed code works in Chrome:

```js
function open(){
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [55, 5]);

  var blobPDF = pdf.output('blob');

  var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF);

  $('#pdf-prueba').attr("src", blobUrl).load(function(e){
    document.getElementById('pdf-prueba').contentWindow.print();
  });
}
```

```html
<iframe id="pdf-prueba" name="pdf-box"></iframe>
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much! I was trying to do it with Ajax and downloading from server

Comment: You are Wellcome. It is a pleasure to share.