# Symfony 1.4 - SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "[url]" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: symfony, iframe, tinymce, blocked

I have problem with tinymce in symfony 1.4 prod.
Any Iframe give me a blank windows with error: "SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "[url]" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

But on dev works fine !!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it appears as if you or a script is trying to interact with a resource from a different origin. My guess is that you are using different protocols (e.g. https) on the production and development environments. Take a look at this page about [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) for more detailed information.

Related questions have been asked and answered before on StackOverflow:

- [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153#25098153)
- [Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8084" from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100205/blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8084-from-accessing-a-cross-origi/42101161#42101161)

Also, it is recommended to upgrade your Symfony installation to a [version](https://symfony.com/roadmap) that is maintained. Symfony 1.4 has not received bug or security fixes for multiple years now. SensioLabs has even [shut down](https://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-symfony-1) the Symfony 1 infrastructure (SVN and plugins) last February.

Comment: I found solution: clients are loging to app from different subdomains (and start iframe from it) but script is starting from main domain. I chcange code and now load js script from client subdomain and that is the trick. 
Yes i know symfony 1,4 is very old but it is not main app.